# Why is Python 3 giving me a name error when the name is defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

the goal of my project is to find exact change using decision-making blocks. All of my code is returning the right answers, except in the answer that is expected to come out as "No Change".

The solution comes out as "No Change" as expected but then is followed by an error code that states

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    if dollars == 1:
NameError: name 'dollars' is not defined
```

Any idea why this might be? Code that I have is below.

```
print("This program asks the user to enter a change amount using integers only,")
print("and outputs the change using the fewest coins.")
input_val = int(input("Enter the change amount as integer:"))



if input_val <= 0:
    print("No Change")

else: 
    dollars = input_val // 100
    input_val %= 100
    quarters = input_val // 25
    input_val %= 25 
    dimes = input_val // 10
    input_val %= 10
    nickels = input_val // 5
    input_val %= 5
    pennies = input_val


if dollars == 1:
    print('%d dollar' % dollars)
elif dollars > 1:
    print('%d dollars' % dollars)

if quarters > 1:
    print('%d quarters' % quarters)
elif quarters == 1:
    print('%d quarter' % quarters)

if dimes > 1:
    print('%d dimes' % dimes)
elif dimes == 1:
    print('%d dime' % dimes)

if nickels > 1:
    print('%d nickels' % nickels)
elif nickels == 1:
    print('%d nickel' % nickels)

if pennies > 1:
    print('%d pennies' % pennies)
elif pennies == 1:
    print('%d penny' % pennies)
```

Comment: You need your program to *stop running* if there's no change to deliver. That means you need to put all of your other code into the else block, OR you can stuff everything into a function and simply `return` after printing there's no change, in the case of < 0.

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure where to put return at? I tried putting it directly below the No Change but it gave me another error.

Comment: When do you want the code to test `dollars==1?  Every time?  Or only after `dollars` is set in the `else` block?  What is the program supposed to do after the `print('no change')?

Comment: If the integer entered is 0 or less, I wanted it to print "No Change" but if it's a positive integer, I still need it to run through the code below that so that it can provide me an answer. Is the return function not working because I don't have it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare variables before using them.

In your code the variables `dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies` are not visible outside the `else` block

```
...
input_val = int(input("Enter the change amount as integer:"))

dollars = 0
quarters = 0
dimes = 0
nickels = 0
pennies = 0


if input_val <= 0:
    print("No Change")
...
```